# how change file attributes to make it executable

Tags: nautilus, execute-command

I want to execute a text file, but I need to change the file preferences so that when I open it, it will actually run the file instead displaying it.  However, I don't know how to change the file preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I think the command you are looking for is `bash`.  Here's a [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AdvancedCommandlineHowto) and example:

```
cd /home/username/Documents
touch runafile
gedit runafile

#!/bin/bash (hit Enter to go down one line)
echo "Hello world"

(type Ctrl-x to exit)
(type y for yes)
(hit Enter to keep the filename)

bash runafile
```

By default in Ubuntu, a plain text file executes by opening in gedit (you can change this by right-clicking the text file/Properties/Open With).  Are you attempting to execute a script?  You can execute any file from terminal like this:

```
cd /desired/path
./fileToExecute
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this through Nautilus (called "File Browser" in recent versions, I think), you can mark a file as executable via the Properties dialog. Right-click on a file, go to Properties, then the Permissions tab, and check "Allow executing file as program".

(You can also set this via the `chmod` command – `chmod u+x file.txt` should do the trick.)

If you try to open it now, you'll be asked:

```
Do you want to run "file.txt", or display its contents?

"file.txt" is an executable text file.

[Run in Terminal] [Display] [Cancel] [Run]
```

`Display` will open it however the system would if it weren't executable. `Run in Terminal` will open a terminal and run it, printing out the normal output. `Run` will run it, without opening a terminal. `Cancel` cancels.

That should do the trick, I think.